# Must a sourcemap have a .map extension?

Tags: source-maps

If I create a source map, must I give it a .map extension, or could I call it .foo, as long as it has the correct headers?

If someone could point to documentation on this, I would be most thankful!

Answer (score 4):

It can have any extension. In the compressed/minified/original file you put a `sourceMappingUrl` comment or `SourceMap` http header that tells the interpreter where to find the source map.

There's no true formal spec for source maps but this is the informal one: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit

Comment: Their answer is somewhat vague: Optionally, a source map will have the same name as the generated file but with a “.map” extension.  For example, for “page.js” a source map named “page.js.map” would be generated.

Comment: it is not vague.The source map file extension doesnt have to be .map that's the point.sourcemap generators choose the .map extension but it could be anyhting,.foo , .bar ... it doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0):

It can be any extension, but **.map** is the most used.  By convention it will have the same name as the target file.

Also the documentation for the Source Maps Proposal has been moved from google docs.  This is the new link:
https://sourcemaps.info/spec.html